# IE Image Loading Parallelism

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So I created an image slideshow player that is suppose to play through 1000's of images at a time.

But rather then ask the browser to *preload* all 1000, I have a batching mechanism which attempts to *preload* in batches.

If I set the batch preload to 25 images then in the network tab I see 25 network requests pop up and images are being loaded (and completed successfully with 200's).

I also have threshold set, so when there are *x* number of images remaining it will start preloading the next 25. I have this set to 15.

The player will step through each image every 1000ms. The initial 25 image request will take a little of 1sec to complete (that is all images). The subsequent 25 batch will take 2sec to complete (so that is now 50 images preloaded).

Now when we get to 125 images preloaded and the next 25 batch is called up we are seeing IE say it takes 5s to decide to make the request (it comes up red in the network tab).

So that is 5s from when it was asked to make the request and the request actually being made. It takes less that 1.5s to complete the request and load the image.

So we are seeing here that there seems to be some kind of rate limiting happening or is there other things we need to be looking at to why IE is refusing to make a request for 5s?

We are using EDGE emulation.

Below is the image preloading. So the `imageObj` is the domain object that as a url of the image.

```
var imageObj = nextBatch[i];
var tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.src = imageObj.Url
imageObj.image = tempImage;
```

This `image` object gets attached to the domain object (`imageObj`).

This is done in a `setTimeout(fn(){}, 0)` to make it async.

I read this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/03/17/internet-explorer-9-network-performance-improvements/) to see if there was anything outstanding. But I didn't see anything initially.

Comment: Try looking at the memory usage. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but we've only hit 100mb

Comment: I've tested this https://jsfiddle.net/d778hnry/3/ and I can't see the behavior you are describing. Try adjusting my fiddle and reproduce the issue there, otherwise there's no way I can help.

Comment: so it could be the server it is hitting.

Comment: Yep, there's a high chance that is the actual issue.